# hostsファイルのlocalhost.localの末につくlocalとは何か

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosts

### わからないこと

Railsでローカルサーバーを立ち上げたときに`http://fogefoge.localhost.local:3200/~`へアクセスして、開発を行っていますが、urlの中に含まれる`.local`の部分を削除するとエラーになります。

hostsファイルの中で下記のように定義することで、IPアドレスと紐付けているということはわかりますが、末に`.local`をつけなければならない理由が分かりません。

```sh
(/etc/hosts)
127.0.0.1  fogefoge.localhost.local
```

下記のように`.local`を除外してhostsファイルを編集後にサーバー立ち上げて、`http://fogefoge.localhost:3200/~`へアクセスしてもRouting Errorになってしまいます。

```sh
(/etc/hosts)
127.0.0.1 fogefoge.localhost
```

何か分かるかたいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `/etc/hosts`を質問文のように編集した状態で、`http://fogefoge.localhost:3200/~`へアクセスするとエラーになりますか?

Comment: はい。hostsファイルを編集した上で、その編集したホストにアクセスするとRouting errorになります。

Comment: 昔マイクロソフトが内部ネットワーク専用に使う例として説明していたらしいですね。今では逆に使わないように言われているようですが。[Active Directoryで「.local」はもうダメ?](https://blog.treedown.net/entry/2018/07/25/010000), [Mac が参加するADのドメイン名で .local を使わないでください。](https://www.picturecode.co.jp/faq/dot-local-domain/), [例示／実験用として利用できるドメイン名](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fwin2k/win2ktips/801exampledom/exampledom.html), [Reserved Top Level DNS Names](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606)

Comment: rails側でなにか設定していませんか？例えば https://note.com/emetselch1984/n/n7dc886b3d4ca や https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails や https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767825/rails-replace-localhost3000-with-custom-domain など

Comment: 皆様コメントありがとうございます。上記コメントにあるとおりrails側で開発環境でドメイン名の設定をしていることが問題でした!!

Answer (score -1):

たんにローカル用のネットワーク（アドレス）、という意味合いかと

Answer (score -1):

詳しくないので端折りますが

`.local` というのは TLD(top-level domain) です。ドメイン名の一部を取り除くなら先頭側の方かも。

---

PDF (2016年12月1日) [IETF事情(DNS関係)](https://www.nic.ad.jp/ja/materials/iw/2016/proceedings/d3/d3-2-fujiwara.pdf) によると

> Multicast DNS (.local)の標準化は dnsextでは好まれなかった
> • A社のプロトコル
>
> dnsext, dnsopとは無関係に標準化
> • IETF Last Callなども通過
> • だれも文句をつけなかった(気付かなかった?)
> • サブマリンRFC?
>
> RFC 6762 Multicast DNSで.local予約
> • 「A社はタダで.local を手にいれた」という声

参考:

- wikipedia.org (英語) [.local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local)
- ja.wikipedia.org [マルチキャストDNS](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88DNS)
- RFC 6762 について [RFC 6762 - Multicast DNS 日本語訳](https://tex2e.github.io/rfc-translater/html/rfc6762.html)